# How many volts would a battery with a dead cell show?

Tags: battery

I read that a battery with a dead cell would not charge above 10.5 volts?  However if each cell is 2 volts wouldn’t it be more correct to say a battery with a dead cell will charge up to anything between 10 and 11.9 volts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, a battery with a dead cell, when fully charged will show the 12.5+vdc as you'd expect. However, once you put it under any type of heavy load (ie: trying to start the vehicle), the voltage will drop down to ~10.5vdc. There is usually a small amount of charge in the cell at first, but is soon wiped out after the battery is put to the test.

Comment: With no load/current flow , it will pretty much show 12 v, it is a chemistry thing.